# Video editor that can read a movie maker's project file and burn to DVD

Tags: video-editing, windows-10, optical-media

On windows prior to 8 we've had an option to burn the project to a DVD within the movie maker but now on win10, the movie maker is no longer avialable.
So the movie-maker compatible software I'm looking for must:

- Read a movie maker project file (the .wlmp file)
- Burn to a DVD

Comment: Must be free, or would you be willing to pay? In the latter case, what's your limit?